# How to test predictive power of ARIMA model

Tags: time-series, predictive-models, econometrics

Once I've fitted an ARIMA model (by choosing, say, the one with the lowest AIC), how can I go about gauging how effective it is at forecasting a given financial time series? Should I somehow incorporate transaction costs?

For example, let's say I found that an ARIMA(2,1,2) is the best fit for predicting daily returns on 10-year treasuries, based on data from 2004-2014 (random example). How can I then gauge how well it actually would have predicted returns? I've thought of several ways I could potentially do it, though I doubt they are technically sound.

I'm doing this for a thesis and selected the topic mainly just to learn how to fit econometric models and test their viability thereafter.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This information is usually in any textbook about time series forecasting. One example would be [here](https://www.otexts.org/fpp/2/5).

The idea is testing forecasting accuracy in general is quite simple. Simple leave out some of the data at the end of your sample and fit the model on the remaining part. Then forecast from the model. Since you have some data left, you can compare it with forecasted values. This is the same process which you would use to test your future forecasts, the difference is that you do not have to wait for actual data to appear. How you compare the forecasts with actual values is up to you, usually some statistic is calculated such as MSE, MAPE or MASE. To make sense of this statistic some protocol of how much data is left out and how much is used for fitting the model is needed. The key words for more information are test and train sets.

Comment: Thanks for the response! The issue I have is that this procedure (if I understood it correctly) assumes that we would use the same model for each estimate. Wouldn't the model technically need to be re-estimated for each data point? Let's say we use data from time t to time t+100 to fit our model. If we use that model to "forecast" t+50, wouldn't that be wrong because we're using a model that is partly based on 50 values ahead of time t+50? It's wrong even if we use it to estimate t+102, because we've excluded t+101 in building our model. Is this right? I'm not sure what a feasible solution is.

Comment: The model needs to be reestimated. Suppose you have data $1,...,T$ you fit the model $M_T$ on this data and forecast the value $T+1$. You wait when the actual data appears at the moment $T+1$. Then you fit the model $M_{T+1}$ based on the data $1,...,T+1$ and forecast the value $T+2$. And so on.